# As can last a graphic card repaired twice?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, imac

I repaired twice my video card, now it works well, but, as can last using Photoshop, Illustrator, etc.? (I do not game) 
Now have a new "chip". I have an iMac 27" mid 2011, so it's so expensive change to a new one.

Comment: "as can last" isn't a phrase we use in English. Did you translate an idiomatic phrase from your native language too literally?

Comment: If it is working, it is okay. No one can predict if it will last.

Comment: @Spiff yes, is from Google Translate sorry...feel free to correct it.. I didn't know how to write it lol.

Comment: @Xavierjazz mmmh.. it can broke in less than 1 week as can broke in less than 1 year?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not quite sure of your intended meaning. Do you mean "How long will it last (before it fails again)?"

Comment: @Spiff yes, Xavierjazz understand perfectly.. so how much lifetime have my video card, in your opinion? (After two repairs)

Comment: Hardware is random. Anything could happen...

Comment: @Spiff: It's a common mistranslation of "how can..." (in this case probably "how long can...") from languages which use the same word for both.

Answer (score 1):

Properly designed/assembled/soldered circuitry usually lasts until the product is so obsolete that you replace it with something more powerful and retire it from use.

A proper repair should last just as long.

Without knowing what was wrong or what repair was needed, or the skill of the technician, it's impossible to guess at how long the repair will last.

I have not heard of any quality problems with the GPUs on mid-2011 27" iMacs, so assuming you took this to an Apple Authorized Service Provider and they swapped out the failing <s>MLB</s> *GPU board* with a new certified board, I would expect it will last until you have no use for a 2011 iMac anymore.

Comment: They welded a **new** chip on **old** my video card, but is the **second time**. The tested the video card over 240° (something like this) and it's not good for my video card (they told me). Let's say the technician was good, and did a good work, I just want to know a range like 1/2 years or 1/2 months (or even less).. so I can take action on my iMac before it breaking..

Comment: You got a substandard repair. Apple never has field service people do soldering. An Apple Authorized Service Provider would have swapped out the failing GPU board with an Apple certified replacement part. There's really no way to predict how long your repair will last.

Comment: My graphic card is broken now lol

Comment: Please take it to an Apple Authorized Service Provider this time.